# Latex, chess board, skak and polyglossia for arabic won't work together

Tags: skak

This is not working it works either for `chessboard` and `skak` or for `polyglossia` but not for both can anyone help me here

```latex
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=15mm}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=mashriq,numerals=arabic]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.0]{Amiri}


\begin{document}
لعب هذا الدور عام الف و تسعمائة و خمسة و سبعين بلا فائدة تذكر

\def\mylist{Ke1, qe2, kf3}
\setchessboard{setpieces=\mylist}
\def\mylist{Ke1, ra1, ke3}
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

chessboard wasn't written with bidi or arabic in mind. Internally it uses in in a number of places `\arabic`, which isn't a good idea as it breaks if packages redefines \arabic to print other number systems. Also it doesn't take RTL into account. As a work around restore (locally) the original arabic definition and switch to LTR before printing a board:

```
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=15mm}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=mashriq,numerals=arabic]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.0]{Amiri}

\makeatletter\let\ori@arabic\@arabic
\newcommand\restorearabic{\let\@arabic\ori@arabic}
\begin{document}
لعب هذا الدور عام الف و تسعمائة و خمسة و سبعين بلا فائدة تذكر

\selectlanguage{english}
\begingroup
\restorearabic
\def\mylist{Ke1, qe2, kf3}
\setchessboard{setpieces=\mylist}
\def\mylist{Ke1, ra1, ke3}
\chessboard
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my question, initially it compiles with no problems. I will check the rest of the files.

Comment: I'm not a sir, I'm a women.

Comment: I've just realised. that very sorry