# Problems viewing chess board in Hebrew document

Tags: hebrew, chessboard, xskak, skak

I'm trying to draw a chess board with `skak` but this is the result:
[image]

As you can see it's opposite...

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[hebrew,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}

\usepackage{skak}
\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\newgame
\showboard
\par
\end{document}
```

Do you know how can show the board correctly? (in Hebrew or other RTL document).

Thank you!

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492475/2388 (which uses chessboard and not the board from skak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the chessboard in `\begin{english}` and `\end{english}`.

```
\documentclass[hebrew,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}

\usepackage{skak}
\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\newgame
\showboard
\par
\end{english}
\end{document}
```